# Redirecting from domain to category in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am running a multisite WoprdPress install where I have configured my install to use sub-domains.

> I have registered and added one domain domain-a which is my main site.
>
> I have recently registered two main domains, domain-a and domain-c,  and I have pointed their DNS records IP address of my multisite.

I need kazisport.co.za and kazisportsoccer.co.za to redirect to a category in phakathi.co.za.

i.e:

kazisport.co.za and kazisportsoccer.co.za

redirect to:

> http://phakathi.co.za/category/sport/

The first option I tried was creating a second site in my multisite network and mapped the two domains to the site. Then I activated a theme. In the theme I used PHP redirect code to redirect to the category in domain-a like this:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'domain-b.co.za' || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'domain-c.co.za')
{
    header("Location: http://domain-a.co.za/category/sport/");
    exit;
}

?>
```

That resulted in a hit and miss in a sense that sometimes the redirection would work and sometimes it wouldn’t work.

Then I replaced the the PHP redirect code with JavaScript like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function gotoPage()
{
    var dns1 = "domain-b.co.za";
    var dns2 = "domain-c.co.za";
    var urlloc = location.href;
    var loc = urlloc.toLowerCase();

    if (loc.indexOf(dns1) != -1){
        location.href="http://domain-a.co.za/category/sport/";
    }
   else if (loc.indexOf(dns2) != -1){
        location.href="http://domain-a.co.za/category/sport/"; 
   }
}
</script>
<body onLoad="gotoPage()">
</body>
</html>
```

That also resulted in hit and miss. Sometimes the redirection would work and sometimes it would not work.
Then I tried htaccess redirect like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-b.co.za$
RewriteRule ^$ http://domain-a.co.za/category/sport/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(server-info|server-status) - [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/php5.fastcgi/*
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/php5.fastcgi/*
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

That did not work at all. I am at a loss and I do not know what I need to do for the redirection to work. I would really appreciate any feedback.

Oh, I need to mention that I am using Varnish Cache.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some luck with a plugin called [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/). After installing the plugin go to:

- Tools -> Redirection
- In the "Source URL" box add "http://domain-b.co.za"
- In the "Target URL" box add "http://domain-a.co.za/category/sport"
- Next click on the "Add redirection" button and the old page should redirect to the new page.
- Do the same for the other site.

(Disclaimer: The above works on a single site, it might work differently on a multisite.)